# How to calculate an inverse Fourier transform of product $\operatorname{rect}(f)$ with $\frac{1}{f+K}$?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, convolution

I need to calculate an inverse Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigl( \frac{1}{f+K} \bigr) \, \operatorname{rect}(Bf) \, e^{j 2\pi f x} \, df$,

where $K$ is a constant, and $B$ is the width of the rectangular box:
$\operatorname{rect}(Bf) = \begin{cases}1 &, -B/2 \leqslant f \leqslant B/2\\ 0 &, \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$.

I ended up at a stage where I need to calculate the convolution $ (e^{-j2\pi Kx} j\pi\operatorname{sgn}(x)) * \operatorname{sinc}(Bx)$.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar to how you would work out the inverse fourier of a step function, the integral is zero outside of this rectangle and so you want to just calculate the integral within this range

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what context is "$f$" a "variable", ... as opposed to being a function?

Comment: @paul_garrett $f$ is the frequency variable in the context of Fourier analysis in engineering.  $j$ is the imaginary unit in an (electrical) engineering context.  Although I tend to use $s$ or $\nu$ for the frequency variable myself.

Comment: thanks, your input is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation:

$$\Pi(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & |t| < \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & |t| > \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$
Hint:

$$\begin{align*} I &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{f+K}\Pi\left(\dfrac{f}{B}\right)e^{j2\pi xf}df\\
\\
&= \int_{-\frac{B}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}} \dfrac{1}{f+K}e^{j2\pi xf}df\\
\\
&= e^{-j2\pi x K}\int_{-\frac{B}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}} \dfrac{1}{f+K}e^{j2\pi x(f+K)}df\\
\\
u &= f+K\\
\\
\dots
\end{align*}$$

Finish the $u$ substitution and do the integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I finally ended up with $C\int_{c_1}^{c_2} \frac{e^u}{u}du$, which can't be represented via elementary functions. Am I right?